# Plotting 3D points with function as contour

Tags: plotting, interpolation

so I have a grid of points in 2D $(x_i, y_i)$, and a function $f(x_i,y_i)$.

I plotted them together like this:

[image]

--

Now I would like to do the same with a grid of 3D points $(x_i, y_i,z_i)$ and a function $f(x_i,y_i,z_i)$.

The best that I could come up with is:

```
maxg = 2;
basis1D = Table[i, {i, -maxg, maxg}];
basis3D = Tuples[basis1D, 3];
projmatrix3D = {{1, 0, 1/Sqrt[2]}, {0, 1, 1/Sqrt[2]}, {0, 0, 0}};
KineticEnergies3D = Map[4*Norm[projmatrix3D.#]^2 &, basis3D];

data = Table[
   Flatten[{basis3D[[i]], KineticEnergies3D[[i]]}], {i, 1, 
    Length[KineticEnergies3D]}];
intf = Interpolation[MapIndexed[{#2, #} &, data]];
Show[ListPointPlot3D[basis3D, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[0.025]]}], 
 ListContourPlot3D[data, Contours -> 20, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

[image]

---

Is it possible to have it a a `CountourPlot3D` (if I interpolate the function)?
Otherwise Is there another function that would be good for this?